# solr index and query utf8

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr4

I have been using solr without any issues on plain text english, but I am now looking to index utf-8 encoded chars.
My question is where do I need to make the settings to allow for utf-8 in solr and how do I query this utf-8 index. It is not clear to me that utf-8 is default.
I cant seem to find any examples online for this and hence my question.

Comment: either you can try solr.ICUNormalizer2FilterFactory for your field or if you are using java for indexing and quering then you can have UTF-8 encoding to the request headers

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti can you please explain why you say `if you are using java for indexing and querying`? I use python to post for index and get for querying - will utf-8 not work by default?

Comment: UTF-8 is the encoding used (by default and unchangable as far as I know, unless you use a different app server), there is nothing you need to configure or change.